# scipy.sparse matrix: subtract row mean to nonzero elements

Tags: python, scipy, updates, sparse-matrix, mean

I have a sparse matrix in [csr_matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) format. For each row i need to subtract row mean from the nonzero elements. The means must be computed on the number of the nonzero elements of the row (instead of the length of the row).
I found a fast way to compute the row means with the following code:

```
# M is a csr_matrix
sums = np.squeeze(np.asarray(M.sum(1)))    # sum of the nonzero elements, for each row
counts = np.diff(M.tocsr().indptr)         # count of the nonzero elements, for each row


# for the i-th row the mean is just sums[i] / float(counts[i])
```

The problem is the updates part. I need a fast way to do this.
Actually what i am doing is to transform M to a [lil_matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html) and perform the updates in this way:

```
M = M.tolil()

for i in xrange(len(sums)):
    for j in M.getrow(i).nonzero()[1]:
        M[i, j] -= sums[i] / float(counts[i])
```

which is slow. Any suggestion for a faster solution?

Comment: I'd try to replicate the row means using `np.repeat` and `counts`, and sub that directly from `M.data` array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one is tricky. I think I have it. The basic idea is that we try to get a diagonal matrix with the means on the diagonal, and a matrix that is like M, but has ones at the nonzero data locations in M. Then we multiply those and subtract the product from M. Here goes...

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import scipy.sparse as sp
>>> a = sp.csr_matrix([[1., 0., 2.], [1.,2.,3.]])
>>> a.todense()
matrix([[ 1.,  0.,  2.],
        [ 1.,  2.,  3.]])
>>> tot = np.array(a.sum(axis=1).squeeze())[0]
>>> tot
array([ 3.,  6.])
>>> cts = np.diff(a.indptr)
>>> cts
array([2, 3], dtype=int32)
>>> mu = tot/cts
>>> mu
array([ 1.5,  2. ])
>>> d = sp.diags(mu, 0)
>>> d.todense()
matrix([[ 1.5,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  2. ]])
>>> b = a.copy()
>>> b.data = np.ones_like(b.data)
>>> b.todense()
matrix([[ 1.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
>>> (d * b).todense()
matrix([[ 1.5,  0. ,  1.5],
        [ 2. ,  2. ,  2. ]])
>>> (a - d*b).todense()
matrix([[-0.5,  0. ,  0.5],
        [-1. ,  0. ,  1. ]])
```

Good Luck! Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, i was thinking to the same thing. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Starting with `@Dthal's` sample:

```
In [92]: a = sparse.csr_matrix([[1.,0,2],[1,2,3]])
In [93]: a.A
Out[93]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.]])

In [94]: sums=np.squeeze(a.sum(1).A)
# sums=a.sum(1).A1   # shortcut
In [95]: counts=np.diff(a.tocsr().indptr)
In [96]: means=sums/counts
In [97]: sums
Out[97]: array([ 3.,  6.])
In [98]: counts
Out[98]: array([2, 3], dtype=int32)
In [99]: means
Out[99]: array([ 1.5,  2. ])
```

`repeat` lets us replicate the `means`, producing an array that matches the matrix `data` in size.

```
In [100]: mc = np.repeat(means, counts)
In [101]: mc
Out[101]: array([ 1.5,  1.5,  2. ,  2. ,  2. ])
```

This `mc` is the same as `@Dthal's` `(b*d).data`.

Now just subtract it from `data`.

```
In [102]: a.data -= mc
In [103]: a.A
Out[103]: 
array([[-0.5,  0. ,  0.5],
       [-1. ,  0. ,  1. ]])
```